# C# Async without framework functions

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a method which is run n times with different parameters, simplified:

```
foreach(var param in params)
    ValueList.Add(SomeMethod(param));
```

I would like to do this:

```
foreach(var param in params)
    TaskList.Add(SomeMethodAsync(param));

foreach(var task in TaskList)
    ValueList.Add(await task);

async Task<SomeValue> SomeMethodAsync(SomeParam p)
{
     //What to do here
     //To make this call async
     return SomeMethod(p);
}
```

How do I have to modify the current Method to apply the async functionality? The `SomeMethod` does not use any framework-functions that provide async; it is fully synchronous.

To describe it in different words: I want n tasks of this method to run asynchronously/simultaneously using the new async/await keywords.

Comment: You may want to read [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx). Also, your second `foreach` loop can be replaced with `var valueList = await Task.WhenAll(taskList);`.

Comment: As I wrote in a comment below; In my case, I am communicating with 14 different servers at once (not webrequest or other async-able operations), there are no resources being used on the client end; I simply need to wait for all operations to finish. However, it seems to take equally long for the sum of operations, no matter if I do `Parrallel.ForEach`, `Jobs.AsParallel.Select(x => SomeMethod(x))` or when I use Tasks. (actually Tasks took a little bit longer than the rest) The sum of time is well above the individual operation timeout time.

Comment: It seems the underlying framework blocks the queries internally, I have no other explanation for the behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your method does not return an asynchronous result then there's no point using async/await.

If you just want to run your methods in parallel, use `Parallel.ForEach`

```
Parallel.ForEach(params, param => ValueList.Add(SomeMethod(param)));
```

If SomeMethod does not use a task, or await any framework async calls then it will run on a single thread, regardless of whether you add async to the method definition.

Your best option in that case is to run SomeMethod in a task.

```
async Task<SomeValue> SomeMethodAsync(SomeParam p)
{
    return await Task.Run<SomeValue>(() => SomeMethod(p));
}
```

Personally I think the Parallel.ForEach is clearer.

Comment: True, but you should be aware that this introduces a new thread. Async doesn't necesseraly introduce new thread.

You can use any kind of Task<T> for awaiting.

Comment: @BoasEnkler True, although the default task scheduler uses the thread pool instead of always spinning up a new task. But if the point is to run them in series and they block, async ain't gonna help.

Comment: Yes also true :-) But I thought more about concurrency and data race issues in general. So the code should be thread safe. And some behavior _may_ change. Depending on the scenario

Comment: Yes I was a bit worried about what type ValueList is, and if it's not a threadsafe list there might be issues.

Comment: Maybe I explained it wrong; I want to know what I have to change in said method to make it work with async/await. Clarified the question.

Comment: How can I find out if the code really does execute in parallel. In my case, I am communicating with 14 different servers at once (not webrequest or other async-able operations) and it takes equally long for the sum of operations, no matter if I do `Parrallel.ForEach`, `Jobs.AsParallel.Select(x => SomeMethod(x))` or when I use Tasks. (actually Tasks took a little bit longer than the rest) The sum of time is well above the individual timeout time.

Answer (score 1):

Just make it a function returning task.

```
Task<SomeValue> SomeMethodAsync(SomePAram p)
{
    return Task<SomeValue>.Run(()=> SomeMethod());
}
```

`SomeMethodAsync` is `awaitable` now.

Comment: you need to add the await keyword after the return otherwise the compiler complains that the return value must be of type SomeValue instead of Task<SomeValue>.

Comment: @CameronMacFarland No , See the method declaration there is no `async`